# Есть ссылка от Yandex Speach - но при попадании символа % буквы превращаются в шифр "%22%D0%B2%D1" - как этот баг обойти?

Tags: php, uri

И снова кириллица! И снова проблемы!
Без знака `%` всё срабатывает нормально, но когда в переменную попадает символ `%`, то весь текст ссылки превращается автоматически в `%22%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%B` тому подобный шестнадцатеричный код.

текст в переменной $weather_string_line:= "`Сейчас в городе высокая влажность (78%). В Красноярске сегодня в 19:00 ожидается +20°C, дождь, легкий ветер.`".

Работает через:

```
print "<br><a href='http://tts.voicetech.yandex.net/generate?text=\"".$weather_string_line."\"&format=mp3&lang=ru-RU&speaker=oksana&emotion=normal&key=[developers_key]'  target='_self'>Проговорить погоду...</a>";
```

Как выйти из положения? Перепарсить текст, найти символ `%` и заменить его на `"процент"` - но это называется костыль.
Может быть есть более рациональное решение, которое я пока не вижу?

---

**UPD:** Пока что реализовал через риплэйс: `$speach_text = str_replace("%", "процентов", $weather_string_line);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что необходимо следовать документации API и стандартам HTTP вообще.

[Документация явно гласит](https://cloud.yandex.ru/docs/speechkit/tts/request):

> Для всех параметров обязательно используйте URL-кодирование.

Ну и, что куда важнее - необходимо следовать стандартам HTTP и форматирования URL. Никакой кириллицы там нет. Вообще ничего нет, только цифры, латинские буквы и символы `-_.`. Всё остальное должно быть представлено в `%code` нотации.

В PHP для URL-кодирования предусмотрена функция [`urlencode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php). Вдобавок, поскольку вы вставляете ссылку в HTML - будет нелишним позаботиться о корректном представлении в HTML. Что иллюстрирует пример в документации:

```
$query_string = 'foo=' . urlencode($foo) . '&bar=' . urlencode($bar);
echo '<a href="mycgi?' . htmlentities($query_string) . '">';
```

---

Большой список параметров обычно удобнее отдать для формирования самому PHP используя функцию [`http_build_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

```
$query_string = http_build_query([
    'text' => 'привет',
    'lang' => 'ru-RU',
    /*...*/
]);

$url = 'http://tts.voicetech.yandex.net/generate?'.$query_string;
```

Так весь query string будет корректно собран и кодирован.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Таким способом она (т.е. робот) и `%` по разному произносит, в зависимость от числа.
А документацию мы не то чтобы не любим читать, у нас просто жизнь короткая... (я на yandex-speach наткнулся при внедрении ip-телефонии одной предпринимательнице, но им технологии не нужны - а мне пригодилось)